# Remove a character from all headers in a CSV file, Java

Tags: java, csv

I have a CSV file, I write from JSON to create the CSV file using

`JFlat flatMe = new JFlap(jsonString);`

`flatMe.json2Sheet().write2csv(path + "filename.csv");`

however, when I write with flatMe, it puts "/" marks on each of the headers, which i don't want. how do i remove a "/" mark from all my headers?
example of the error: [header error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPADM.png)
i want to remove the / mark before each of those headers. how can i go about this (using java code)? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At https://github.com/opendevl/Json2Flat#output-csv you'll find a solution: use `headerSeparator()`, e. g.

```
flatMe.json2Sheet().headerSeparator().write2csv(path + "filename.csv");
```